# How to prevent fixed div block touch scroll

Tags: html, css

I have container div which creates scroll when content overflows, as the content's sibling I want to place some floating buttons that are position fixed.

However on mobile devices, the container div blocks user being able to scroll, is there a way to solve this?

things I have tried:

- `pointer-event: none` works but user won't be able to interact with whatever inside of the fixed div.
- z-Index:  doesn't work
- works if the scroll area is window, but I need it to be a inner scroll

please see below example in mobile view (chrome devtool) and try to scroll with mouse "touch", noticed if you start scroll from red area, it doesn't work

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 2500px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.btn-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
  padding:64px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `pointer-events: none` works but user won't be able to interact with whatever inside of the fixed div.

reset it for the child elements:

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 2500px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.btn-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
  padding:64px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  pointer-events: none
}
.btn-container>* {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```